# Not receiving response for a XMLHttpRequest Get

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This is driving me crazy. I made this work in VB but cannot get this code to work. Piecing the URL together works correctly, as I can output it and then copy the address and it produces an output.  However, in this code I don't receive anything back and the Network Error alert is triggered.  I've looked at other threads here and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong which means it's right in front of me. Any help would really be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <label for="streetInput">Street:</label>
    <input type="text" id="streetInput"><br><br>
    
    <label for="cityInput">City:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cityInput"><br><br>
    
    <label for="stateInput">State:</label>
    <input type="text" id="stateInput"><br><br>
    
    <label for="zipInput">Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zipInput"><br><br>
    
    <button onclick="searchCensusData()">Search Census Data</button>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>

    function searchCensusData() {
        const street = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('streetInput').value);
        const city = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('cityInput').value);
        const state = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('stateInput').value);
        const zip = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('zipInput').value);
        const newstreet = street.replaceAll("%20", "+");
        const jjson = "json";
        const benchmark = "Public_AR_Current";
        const vintage = "Current_Current";
        const combined = newstreet.concat('&city=',city,'&state=',state,'&zip=',zip,'&benchmark=',benchmark,'&vintage=',vintage,'&format=',jjson);
        const Url = "https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?street=";
        const apiUrl = Url.concat(combined);
            
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = apiUrl;

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET",apiUrl); 
            xhr.send();
            
            xhr.onerror = function() { // only triggers if the request couldn't be made at all
                alert(`Network Error`);
            };

           const response = xhr.responseText;
           const geoInfoPos = response.indexOf("Census Tracts");
           const geoInfo = response.substr(geoInfoPos,11);            
           
         }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your browser developer tools Network tab and browser console will have more detailed info as to the nature of the error.

Comment: You are not using the load event! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/load_event

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/load_event) so you are trying to read the reponse before it comes back. You handle the error state correctly. You want to do the same with load.

```js
xhr.onload = function () {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
```

Comment: It’s still triggering the network error
            xhr.onload = function () {
              const response = xhr.responseText;
              const geoInfoPos = response.indexOf("Census Tracts");
              const geoInfo = response.substr(geoInfoPos,11);      
              document.getElementById('result').innerText = geoInfoPos;              
            };
            xhr.onerror = function() { // only triggers if the request couldn't be made at all
              alert(`Network Error`);
            };
            xhr.open("GET", apiUrl, false); 
            xhr.send();

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error? What do you see in the developer console? Did you inspect the message returned from the server?

Comment: sorry it got cut off there.  I'm getting a no 'access-control-allow-origin’ header present on the requested resource.

Comment: So they are not letting you make a request. CORS is like a person giving you a key to access their house. If they don't give you the key, you can not enter the house. They are not setting the CORS header, so you can not get the content.

Comment: That's so strange.  I setup a VB script to do the same thing in MS Access (no judging!) and it worked flawlessly.  I'll have to figure out a workaround.  Thanks for the help!!  I really appreciate the quick responses!